# Why is my buffer output chopped up? c++ socket programming

Tags: python, c++, sockets, c++11, tcp

I'm trying to open a TCP socket and dump the data into a file. I'm trying to get the same results as in my `python3` version. The output to console and the file line by line, see below:

```
python3 logsvrd.py

Server started on port: 8901
Client (172.16.1.1, 4937) connected

b'<166>%ASA-6-414007: TCP syslog server connection restored.  New connections allowed.\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 778663 for OUTSIDE:172.31.252.15/514 to INSIDE:172.16.1.12/514 duration 0:02:10 bytes 258\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63215 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/63215\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 778712 for OUTSIDE:172.25.5.10/8443 (172.25.5.10/8443) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63215 (68.202.229.140/63215)\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 776408 for OUTSIDE:17.154.66.156/443 to INSIDE:172.16.1.112/58335 duration 1:06:50 bytes 3651 Connection timeout\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-305012: Teardown dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.112/58335 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/13531 duration 1:06:50\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 778706 for OUTSIDE:172.25.5.10/8443 to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63193 duration 0:00:30 bytes 0 SYN Timeout\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-305012: Teardown dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63193 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/63193 duration 0:00:30\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-305012: Teardown dynamic UDP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/58331 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/58331 duration 0:02:33\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 776406 for OUTSIDE:17.154.66.156/443 to INSIDE:172.16.1.112/58333 duration 1:06:55 bytes 11658 Connection timeout\n'
b'<166>%ASA-6-305012: Teardown dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.112/58333 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/58333 duration 1:06:55\n'
```

When I do this in `c++` it is producing chopy results:

```
<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
E:172.16.1.117/62572 (68.202.229.140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
.1/0
E:172.16.1.117/62572 (68.202.229.140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
E:172.16.1.117/62572 (68.202.229.140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
.1/0
E:172.16.1.117/62572 (68.202.229.140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 778219 for OUTSIDE:172.25.5.10/8443 to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/62550 duration 0:00:30 bytes 0 SYN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-305012: Teardown dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/62550 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/62550 duration 0:00:30
 SYN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 778171 for INSIDE:172.16.1.117/68 to identity:172.16.1.1/67 duration 0:02:02 bytes 620
0
 SYN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 778172 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/58307 duration 0:02:02 bytes 163
YN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 778173 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/56906 duration 0:02:01 bytes 147
YN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-604103: DHCP daemon interface INSIDE:  address granted 0110.4a7d.af14.fa (172.16.1.122)
7/56906 duration 0:02:01 bytes 147
YN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
ion 0:02:01 bytes 147
YN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
.1/0
ion 0:02:01 bytes 147
YN Timeout
140/62572)
<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61908 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/61908
<166>%ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 778266 for OUTSIDE:172.16.82.10/389 (172.16.82.10/389) to INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61908 (68.202.229.140/61908)
<166>%ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 778221 for OUTSIDE:10.201.218.61/443 to INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61901 duration 0:00:30 bytes 0 SYN Timeout
 TCP connection 778266 for OUTSIDE:172.16.82.10/389 (172.16.82.10/389) to INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61908 (68.202.229.140/61908)
<166>%ASA-6-305012: Teardown dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61901 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/61901 duration 0:00:30
0 SYN Timeout
 TCP connection 778266 for OUTSIDE:172.16.82.10/389 (172.16.82.10/389) to INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61908 (68.202.229.140/61908)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778267 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.122/49834 (172.16.1.122/49834)
onnection 778266 for OUTSIDE:172.16.82.10/389 (172.16.82.10/389) to INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61908 (68.202.229.140/61908)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778268 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/22843 (172.16.1.117/22843)
onnection 778266 for OUTSIDE:172.16.82.10/389 (172.16.82.10/389) to INSIDE:172.16.1.122/61908 (68.202.229.140/61908)
<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic UDP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/49549 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/49549
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778269 for OUTSIDE:216.58.216.78/443 (216.58.216.78/443) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/49549 (68.202.229.140/49549)
<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/62591 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/62591
<166>%ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 778270 for OUTSIDE:216.58.216.78/443 (216.58.216.78/443) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/62591 (68.202.229.140/62591)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778271 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63224 (172.16.1.117/63224)
<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic UDP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/57906 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/57906
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778272 for OUTSIDE:192.168.10.2/53 (192.168.10.2/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/57906 (68.202.229.140/57906)
91)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778271 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63224 (172.16.1.117/63224)
<166>%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778272 for OUTSIDE:192.168.10.2/53 (192.168.10.2/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/57906 (68.202.229.140/57906)
91)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778271 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63224 (172.16.1.117/63224)
<166>%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 172.16.1.123/0 gaddr 172.16.1.1/0 laddr 172.16.1.1/0
.1/0
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778272 for OUTSIDE:192.168.10.2/53 (192.168.10.2/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/57906 (68.202.229.140/57906)
91)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778271 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63224 (172.16.1.117/63224)
<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic TCP translation from INSIDE:172.16.1.117/62594 to OUTSIDE:68.202.229.140/62594
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778272 for OUTSIDE:192.168.10.2/53 (192.168.10.2/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/57906 (68.202.229.140/57906)
91)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778271 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63224 (172.16.1.117/63224)
<166>%ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 778274 for OUTSIDE:172.25.5.10/8443 (172.25.5.10/8443) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/62594 (68.202.229.140/62594)
ction 778272 for OUTSIDE:192.168.10.2/53 (192.168.10.2/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/57906 (68.202.229.140/57906)
91)
<166>%ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 778271 for OUTSIDE:172.31.253.8/53 (172.31.253.8/53) to INSIDE:172.16.1.117/63224 (172.16.1.117/63224)
```

Here is the code:

```
// Handle errors with messages
void error(const char *msg){
  perror(msg);
  exit(1);
}

// Handle TCP client
void HandleClient(int clntSession, std::string logmsg_path){
  char buffer[BUFSIZE];

  // build the bin file time stamp
  std::time_t epoch = std::time(nullptr);
  std::string ts = std::to_string(epoch);
  std::string logmsg = logmsg_path + "log_msg.bin." + ts;
  std::ofstream bin_outfile(logmsg, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);

  // receive syslog message
  ssize_t numBytesRcved = recv(clntSession, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
  if (numBytesRcved <0) {
    error("revived failed");
  }

  // Send received string and receive again until end of stream
  while(numBytesRcved > 0){

    // Echo message back to client
    ssize_t numBytesSent = send(clntSession, buffer, numBytesRcved, 0);
    if (numBytesSent < 0) {
      error("send failed");
    }
    else if (numBytesSent != numBytesRcved) {
      error("unexpected number of bytes sent");
      numBytesRcved = recv(clntSession, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
    }

    // See if there is more data to receive
    numBytesRcved = recv(clntSession, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0 );
    if (numBytesRcved < 0) {
      error("recive faild");
    }

    // write buffer to binary file and std::cout
    //bin_outfile << buffer;
    std::cout << buffer;
  }
  close(clntSession); // close the session when done
}
```

Comment: Farrrrrrr too much code here. Get rid of the Python and produce a _minimal_ C++ testcase. Debug until you've narrowed down the issue. This isn't a debugging service!

Comment: If the data contains embedded nulls, don't use functions or code that terminate on the null (such as printf using the `%s` formatter, and `std::cout << buffer;`)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are correct, I changed it to just output to bin file and when I open it in `bvi` it's all there like it should be. Thanks.

Comment: @insecure-IT I posted an answer.  You're not the first to make this mistake, believe me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you are not doing that you should be doing is to make sure that you're using the appropriate functions to output the full data.

Your current code uses functions that will stop processing the returned buffer when a NULL byte is encountered.  Functions such as `printf` using the `%s` format specifier, and `std::cout` when given a character pointer as the argument to `operator <<` will stop on the NULL.  If your data consists of embedded NULLs, you will not process (or see) the full data, thus giving you truncated results.

The `numBytesRcved` variable that you have declared should be used in some way to inform subsequent code exactly how to handle your returned buffer.  So for example, if you wanted to output the buffer to `std::cout`,  instead of this:

```
std::cout << buffer;
```

it should be this:

```
std::cout.write(buffer, numBytesRcvd);
```

The same thing can be said for functions such as `strcpy`, `strlen`, etc, that stop on NULL bytes -- do not use them to process or manipulate buffers that can potentially have embedded NULL.

---

Just to add (because I see this mistake many times when using `std::string` to store the buffer):

For things such as `std::string`.  Instead of something like this:

```
std::string s = buffer;
```

it should be this:

```
std::string s = std::string(buffer, numBytesRcvd);
```

or if appending to existing data:

```
std::string s;
//... assume s has data already, now append
s.append(buffer, numBytesRcvd);
```